# webpage not loading only in ios9 safari browser

Tags: javascript, performance, mobile-safari, ractivejs, ios9.1

I am facing one problem for rendering some of my webpages in iOS 9 safari browser. these pages are not rendering at all in this browser but the same pages are working fine for desktop and other devices browser including IOS 8 and below.

what are the difference between iOS 8 safari and iOS 9 safari?
 what coud be the solution for this issue?
 how to debug this issue?
 do anybody faced this problem already?

here we are using ractiveJs frontend templating (legacy version for IE support) and related json data is being fetched by Ajax call. Jquery and some additional JavaScript library are included here.

[Please refer attached image for memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuB4J.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with Ractive on iOS 9, so far up to 9.2. The problem is with large templates which runs into a memory leak in Safari. [An issue](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/2193) was opened for this but it has since been closed without providing a fix. Instead the Ractive team is waiting for Apple to fix Safari, although I haven't been able to find any mention that Apple will do such a thing.

You have a couple of choices to work around this problem:

- Split large templates into multiple [partials](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/partials).
- Pre-parse your template. I don't know how to do this but you could start by reading some of the responses to [the issue](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/2193) I linked to. You can get the parser code from [here](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/tree/master/src/parse).